# How, with passport.js's passport-local or other Node.js tools can I have the equivalent of full CRUD?

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, passport.js, passport-local

I've looked at the documentation in passport.js and the passport-local strategy seems markedly incomplete.

If you have a populated base of Users who have their passwords in whatever form, then from that it's plain from the docs at http://passportjs.org/docs/username-password how to let people try to log in, get a useful failure message (and, from a usability perspective, nicely inform which one it was of a username or password that didn't match), and if they've given valid credentials, log in.

However, there is a sort of CRUD set of basic functionality surrounding username-password authentication. Often it is desired for people to be able to create their own accounts; also if they have forgotten their passwords, they should be able to request a "reset password" link and be able to get to the point of being able to log in without having a plaintext password emailed to them. All of this is a bit of a chore, but it is a base that needs to be covered like various applications need CRUD to be covered.

The documentation I've read about passport-local doesn't discuss this, and what I was looking for looked like a way with Mongoose to manually reinvent this quasi-CRUD side of username-password authentication. I don't know if this a limitation of passport-local or the docs.

If I want to have routine features for a public website with accounts that people can create for themselves, and I'm already using Express.js and (negotiably) Passport.js, what are my options?

Thanks,

Comment: It's best not to expose which part of the login credentials caused the failure, though, from a security perspective.

Comment: I know it's better from a security perspective, and security and usability can be at loggerheads: give either concern free reign, and the other will be trashed. But in this case I'd go with usability.

Comment: Have you looked at [Stormpath](https://stormpath.com)? Disclaimer: I work there. We've implemented best practices for registration (you must validate your email) and password reset (we send you a link with a token), and this is all readily available through our [express-stormpath](https://github.com/stormpath/stormpath-express) module.

Comment: Digging into your solution; thanks! Could you repeat your comment as a response so I have the option of accepting it?

Comment: One comment about secret keys: On LUM systems, one can easily enough generated 1024 bytes from /dev/random, hex-encoded for a secret. In terms of secret management, you might default to encoded bytes from /dev/random and allow the user to override rather than asking the user to specify a secret key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking for a full CRUD user management system, you can't really beat something like [Stormpath](https://stormpath.com/).

Using their express.js library instantly gives you a full CRUD system (with Node / Express / Restify / Loopback / Python / Django / Flask / etc...) libraries for managing / working with your users.

Here's their express.js library docs: https://docs.stormpath.com/nodejs/express/

Essentially, what they do is:

- They'll store your user accounts.
- You use their middleware to create / login / manage users.
- You can use their middlewares to restrict pages by login, group, API authentication, etc.
- You can use their libraries to search / sort / create / update / delete users / API keys / applications / groups.

It's very feature complete, and well documented.

I'm the author of the above library, so I'm a bit biased, but it's honestly quite useful =)

Comment: Thanks for weighing in. My present difficulty is that I believe what I need to do if an unauthenticated user is supposed to log in is supply a JWT and redirect to Stormpath. My identifier is lizard-mint, and I haven't been able to see this in the docs. What should I do to redirect a user to a Stormpath login page?

Comment: You can use the `stormpath.loginRequired` middleware on your route to force this to happen automatically =)